# Program is not opening after writing TcpClient client = list.AcceptTcpClient();

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I have to display client ip address on label on windows form 
this is my code which i have written

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPEndPoint end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
        TcpListener list = new TcpListener(end);
        list.Start();

        TcpClient client = list.AcceptTcpClient();

        label5.Text = client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString();
    }
```

When I comment on TcpClient client = list.AcceptTcpClient() my program starts but definitely it wont display ip address of client

Any Suggestions please

Comment: Well, LocalEndPoint is the **local** endpoint. You probably need the remote endpoint. Looks like code was copied from somewhere.

Comment: Yeah exactly its copied from my visual studio.

Comment: My windows form got freeze after writing 
list.Start();
TcpClient client = list.AcceptTcpClient();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AcceptTcpClient()` is a blocking method. If you call it from your `Load` event handler, which is itself called in the UI thread, you will block the thread that is supposed to be handling the user interface. Nothing will happen in your program until a client actually attempts to connect and the `AcceptTcpClient()` method returns.

You can fix this issue by using the asynchronous version of the method. For example:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPEndPoint end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
    TcpListener list = new TcpListener(end);
    list.Start();

    TcpClient client = await list.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

    label5.Text = client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString();
}
```

This will let the `Form1_Load()` method return  when the `AcceptTcpClientAsync()` method is called, allowing the UI thread to continue working. If and when a client does connect, execution of your `Form1_Load()` method will resume, copying the result of the accept operation into the `client` variable and then executing the next statement (i.e. updating `label5.Text`).

Of course, as the code stands now, you don't appear to do anything with the accepted `TcpClient` (other than to report its IP/port information). Presumably you intend to add more code to handle the actual client connection. As you do, please always keep in mind the above; you need to always keep the UI thread free to operate, and using the `async`/`await` idiom is the best way to do that.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help